# How do I get events to show in daily and weekly views in Apple Calendar?

Tags: calendar

I have multiple iCloud and Google calendars connected to Apple Calendar on both my Mac and iPhone.

When I view the calendar on the Mac (running Ventura) in monthly view most of the events show, except when there is too many to fit in the cell for a particular day. However, if I switch to daily or weekly calendar view, only "all day" events are shown. Events scheduled between 2 times e.g. a meeting etc, are not shown. They exist in the calendar, as they are shown in monthly view, and on my iPhone.

Have I inadvertently set something so that these events are not displayed?

Comment: Have you tried scrolling up and down? I ask only because it's the only possible explanation I can come up with after perusing all the options and settings in Calendar

Comment: @Ezekiel yes, I have tried scrolling, and chaining how many hours are shown at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anybody else has this issue and finds this question: I spoke to Apple Support about this, their suggestion was to [reboot my Mac into safe mode](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201262), which has resolved the issue - I can now see my calendar entries in day/week view.

Comment: This worked for me.